# html file not loading google maps and current location

Tags: google-maps, java, html

I have a html file that when I click on it, it should open in a browser but it does not load. The link of the html opens and loads the image. Below is the link:

http://cambridgeaviation.org/location/Intro_Direction.html

Comment: the like to the htlm file is https://www.dropbox.com/personal?preview=Intro_Direction.html

Comment: Would you be able to create a code snippet from your HTML to illustrate what you think may be the problem and post it in your question, please?  Otherwise, this seems to be simply asking "can you debug my code?" and we do not offer a code debugging service.  What we do offer is help with code snippets.